# convert a date string from mysql table to a specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the example below I need `20-Jan-2021` inside `inpdate`
i.e. convert a string - `2021-01-20` - given from server side - to a corresponding format
any help?

```js
let a = "2021-01-20";  // given from mysql table
let b = ???;
$('#inpdate').val(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='inpdate'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Date object from the date given here and access its properties to build a string to your liking afterwards:

```js
function reformatDate(dateString) {
  const dateObject = new Date(dateString);
  return `${dateObject.getDate()}-${dateObject.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' })}-${dateObject.getFullYear()}`;
}

console.log(reformatDate('1970-01-01'));
console.log(reformatDate('2021-01-20'));
```

Comment: pls try on my snippet, getting syntax error

Comment: There we go, overlooked some minor mistakes :D Should work now!

Comment: @PascalStockert - this could be a better answer by turning it into a runnable stack-snippet.

Comment: it works, but... maybe there is a shorter way

Comment: @Stephen P I'm somewhat new to actually answering questions on here rather than just "getting inspired" - thank you for the heads-up though!

Comment: And @qadenza - this is the shortest way I know without defining an array of month-abbreviations yourself. But maybe someone else has a better idea :)

Comment: np @Pascal — just press Ctrl+M or the `<>` tag-looking button in the editor that has the tooltip "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M", paste your JS in there... maybe add a console.log(b) to show the result. Your answer doesn't even need html or css. It's like using jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Uuh fancy! Yeah, never worked with codepen or jsfiddle before either. Oh well, thanks for the pointer again!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Example

```js
let a = "2021-01-20T11:59:59"; // given from mysql table
function d2fm(str, dl) {
  var dt = new Date(str);
  var m = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
  ];
  var yy = dt.getFullYear(), mm = m[dt.getMonth()], dd = dt.getDate();
  return dd + dl + mm + dl + yy;
}
$('#inpdate').val(d2fm(a, "-"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='inpdate'>
```

You might look at https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

> `$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )`

Comment: thanks, but - so much code for such a minor task, can't believe there is no a simple way. btw I need `20-Jan-2021` and not reverse